# What is a word for someone who is good at making connections between different subjects?

Tags: single-word-requests

It should have a positive connotation and be an adjective.

> Bob's X thinking by applying an obscure idea from computer science to his dissertation on the impact of wine production on the rise of classical Roman architecture.

The example is exaggerated intentionally to epitomize what the word would suggest.

The word should also be applicable to describing a person.

> Bob is one of the most X people I know. For example, he...

Comment: Have you considered *agile*? It fits the bill.

Comment: @vickyace Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question that the word should be applicable to describing people. When "agile" is used to describe a person, you think more about their physical quickness than their mental abilities.

Comment: Try ***out-of-the-box***:  *Bob’s out-of-the-box thinking...*. Oh, I guess not directly applicable to a person.

Comment: Consider the following. The act of seeing or making connections among things is different than characteristics that enable someone to see the said connections. Which one do you want?

Comment: Perhaps ***pragmatic*** would work.

Comment: @vickyace Both, I guess. I was mainly thinking of the underlying traits than the act, though it would be helpful to know how to describe that too. If it has to be two distinct words then that's fine.

Comment: You may be interested in this article from [Thinkadvisor.com](http://www.thinkadvisor.com/2011/04/01/matchers-and-mismatchers-how-to-work-with-impossib); the term 'matcher' is perhaps broadened enough to be appropriate to describe the person in your example (but 'matching' hardly works as an adjective here).

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes! Eclectic was the word I was looking for. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **eclectic** to imply a creative and fresh *mix of ideas*.

[Definition of Eclectic:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eclectic)

> Combining elements from a variety of sources: "a popular bar patronized by an eclectic collection of artists, writers, secretaries and aging soldiers on reserve duty" (Curtis Wilkie) - American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.

Answer (score 4):

This used to be called "lateral thinking" and "lateral" was used as an adjective as in "Bob is one of the most lateral people I know."  The expression has fallen out of use but I don't know of another word that specifically pertains.
Wikipedia says of it 
"Lateral thinking is solving problems through an indirect and creative approach, using reasoning that is not immediately obvious and involving ideas that may not be obtainable by using only traditional step-by-step logic. The term was promulgated in 1967 by Edward de Bono. He cites as an example the Judgment of Solomon, where King Solomon resolves a dispute over the parentage of a child by calling for the child to be cut in half, and making his judgment according to the reactions that this order receives."

Answer (score 0):

Seeing connections or similarities between different subjects reflects thinking about them abstractly or conceptually, the level at which they are similar.  Terms like "**abstract thinker**" or "**conceptual**" could apply.